# IntelliJ cannot run JUnit test class

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to run my JUnit test class in IntelliJ and I can't manage to get this to work. When I click `run`, I only get to see the option to run the Main class.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have JUnit plug-in enabled? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the [IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: @CrazyCoder The JUnit plug-in is enabled. How can I give an example if can't run the test? I can't give any errors as I just don't get the option to run it.

Comment: Zip and share the project and the IDE logs, upload it at some file sharing service, provide the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test class needs to be `public`:

```
public class AlchemicIngredientTest {
...
```